# Program that reads from 2 excel files and enables users to search relevant fields from both files

Tags: c#, excel

This is supposed to be a program that reads from 2 excel files, stores the data in two arrays and enables users to search via textbox for a specific zip/place and upon the input in the search box to be prompted with the place/s that relate/s to it via lable or vice versa.

My problem is that it takes too much time for the files to be red. I am open for suggestions how to shorten the read time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ;

namespace ExcelDateilesen_1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] zip = new string[3000];
    string[] place = new string[3000];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open
            (@"C:\Users\ggr\Documents\plz.xlsx");
        Excel.Worksheet objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets["Tabelle1"];

        Excel.Range objCell;
        int i = 1;
        do
        {
            objCell = objWorksheet.Cells[i, 1];

            if (objCell.Value == null) break;

            if (objCell.Value is string)
            {
                zip[i - 1] = objCell.Value;
            }
            i++;
        } while (true);
        objWorkbook.Close();
        objExcel.Quit();

        Excel.Application objExcel1 = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook objWorkbook1 = objExcel1.Workbooks.Open
            (@"C:\Users\ggr\Documents\ort.xlsx");
        Excel.Worksheet objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook1.Worksheets["Tabelle1"];

        Excel.Range objCell1;

        int j = 1;
        do
        {
            objCell1 = objWorksheet1.Cells[j, 1];

            if (objCell1.Value == null) break;

            if (objCell1.Value is string)
            {
                place[j - 1] = objCell1.Value;
            }
            j++;
        } while (true);
        objWorkbook1.Close();
        objExcel1.Quit();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It took about 20 seconds to read each Excel file containing 3000 rows of data using your code. Instead of looping through the Excel file and looking for a null cell, I created a method (ReadSheet) that would take an Excel worksheet and return a string array of the first column of data for 3000 rows. I used an object `Array` to get all the cell values, and then cast it to a string array. Reading was much faster. Unfortunately I was unable to take advantage of the `worksheet.UsedRange` function to get all the rows no matter how many, because it kept giving me the wrong number. I will have to look into this. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Changed to UsedRange to get all cells. The problem I had was with the excel sheet I was using.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  string[] zip;
  string[] place;
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Excel.Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\John\Desktop\cs\TestExcel2_3000.xlsx");
    Excel.Worksheet objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets["Tabelle1"];

    zip = ReadSheet(objWorksheet);
    objWorkbook.Close();
    Excel.Workbook objWorkbook1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\John\Desktop\cs\TestExcel3_3000.xlsx");
    Excel.Worksheet objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook1.Worksheets["Tabelle1"];

    place = ReadSheet(objWorksheet1);
    objWorkbook1.Close();
    objExcel.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objWorkbook);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objWorkbook1);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objExcel);
  }

  private string[] ReadSheet(Excel.Worksheet inSheet)
  {
    Excel.Range targetCells = inSheet.UsedRange;
    //Excel.Range targetCells = inSheet.Range["A1:A3000"];
    Array allValues = (Array)targetCells.Cells.Value;
    return allValues.Cast<string>().ToArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: Same Problem - it wouldn´t get the number of non-empty cells. I explicitly defined the number of rows as in the Excel sheet (not as in my Code above - the cells are 2652) and then by iterating through the cells-Array would assign those values to the adequat predefined string Array with range No. cells - 1 because of the 0th element (therefore the [i-1] and [j-1] to start from the 0th element in the array). My logic was that using this approach there won't be any null values, but i kept getting exceptions and the system propmted me with messages that there can't be any "null" values.

Comment: I not sure if I understand your comment. I thought your problem was: _My problem is that it takes too much time for the files to be red._ If there are empty cells in your range and you want to ignore them or not I am unclear on what you want to accomplish. I was just trying to address a quicker read of the files as the last line before you code states. What do you want to read into the arrays?

Comment: You code as it is, it will stop reading the file as soon as it reaches a null cell. So I am curious how your array could end up with a null value.

Comment: Where do you get these exceptions?

Comment: It happened when I set the number of elements of both arrays to be equal to the actual number of rows in the excel files. But the mistake is on my side - i've set the array to be 1 element smaller than the count of rows. The algorithm seems to work fine - the code compiles.

Comment: The goal of the program is to read zip-s and place's names from text/excel file and use them as data source for a form that will allow users to serach for the zip code of a particular place or the other way around(pretty simple). I've managed to overcome the time issue by copying the data into .txt files and using Streamreader. Anyways, will be glad to learn a faster way to read from excel file.

Comment: @G.Grigorov… Did you try my answer? As I said in the answer, using your code, it took around 20 seconds to read an excel file of 3000 rows of data. My solution reading the same files took less than 2 seconds. So I guess my answer did not help speed up the read times for you? Your code loops through the excel spreadsheet and this is an expensive/time consuming process changing ranges etc…

Comment: @G.Grigorov… But back to your last comment… In your supplied code, you have absolutely nothing in relation to the form and its components. Your code simply reads in two files into two arrays. From what you describe it sounds like on a form you may need a `DataGridView` and a couple of text boxes. You can fill the `DataGridView` with the items you read in. But you have none of this in you code. Set up what you want your form to do, then use the data that you have in your array(s) to display on the form.

Comment: @G.Grigorov… Get that going and post another question if you have problems. I find it ODD that you would have one file that holds a zip and another file that holds a place that is indexed to a zip in the other file? Why not one file with zip and place on one line? If there ARE two files it doesn’t mean you have to make two arrays. This simply makes your code harder to manage. Keep it simple, make a ZipPlace class and as you read in the file(s) you can create a bunch of ZipPlace objects and put them neatly in a list that you can display, sort, filter etc... Just a thought.